# Coldfusion CFIF statement

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to check the contents of 2 form elements against existing database enties and then if either of them are differnet run a conditional option but I am having some issues as the below does not seem to be working. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<cfquery name="qLiveService" datasource="#application.datasource#">
 SELECT broadcastPackage, AdditonalDVDs 
 FROM dbo.tributes
 WHERE profileID = 122>
</cfquery>   



<cfif qLiveService.broadcastPackage is form.broadcastPackage and qLiveService.AdditonalDVDs is form.AdditonalDVDs >

<!--- do something -->

<cfelse>


<!--- of one was different now run the code in this area -->

</cfif>
```

Comment: "Not working" is too vague a description :) Can you elaborate? Also, what are the actual values you are comparing and the data types of the two columns?

Comment: I'm sure this will be easy to solve I you provide a little more info.

Comment: what is the symbol ">" doing at the end of your query?

Comment: like Leigh said, dump the query to the screen and dump out the two form fields too. That should help you solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>      WHERE profileID = 122>
> ```

Remove the extra `>` after 122

If you are using quotes " around your variables, you need to add pound # signs to ensure the values are evaluated. For example:

```
<cfset a = "bob">
<cfset b = "bob">
<cfset x = 5>
<cfset y = 5>
<cfif ( a is "#b#" ) and ( x is "#y#" )>
    Equal
<cfelse>
    Not Equal
</cfif>
```

You do not need pound signs if you are not using quotes:

```
<cfif ( a is b ) and ( x is y )>
    Equal
<cfelse>
    Not Equal
</cfif>
```

You can try to `<cfset` the variable as well - like above.

Comment: Their usage of # signs is correct. Aside from the extraneous `>` symbol DB3 mentioned above I do not see any obvious problems. I suspect it is actually a logic or implicit conversion problem.

Answer (score -2):

correct where condition in query "WHERE profileID = 122"
and on if condition

```
<cfoutput>
<cfif #qLiveService.broadcastPackage# eq #val(form.broadcastPackage)# and   #qLiveService.AdditonalDVDs# is #val(form.AdditonalDVDs)# >
  Equal
    <cfelse>
Not Equal
</cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: There is no need for `#` signs in that context. Nor the `cfoutput` tags, as the code is not actually outputting anything. See [When do I use pound signs](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/2/10/when.do.i.use.pound.signs). Also, without knowing what types of values are being compared, it is impossible to say whether adding `val()` will help or harm.